# Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2) error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, prepared-statement

I get the following error when I try to talk to my SQL database.This method gets two string values from a JSP page. The code gets this weeks dates set by the first int.
However, the problem is when I'm trying to talk to the database. It must be a syntax error. I've tried using different brackets

```
public String getSpecificSpot(String day, String hour) {

    String result = "";
    int dayNo= Integer.parseInt(day);


    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    //System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    String monday = "";
    monday = df.format(cal.getTime());
    //System.out.println(monday);

    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, dayNo);
    String currentDay = df.format(cal.getTime());
    String currentDay2= currentDay;
    System.out.println("Current DAY: "+currentDay);

    boolean found = false;
    Connection c = DBHelperClass.getConnection();
    String query = "Select * from timetableslot WHERE date BETWEEN ? 00:00:00.00' AND ? 23:59:59.999' and time= ? ";
    if (c != null) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement inserter = c.prepareStatement(query);
            inserter.setString(1, currentDay);
            inserter.setString(2, currentDay2);
            inserter.setString(3, hour);

            System.out.println("validating user: " + query);
            ResultSet resultSet = inserter.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {

                //result = resultSet.getInt("classID");
                result= String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("slotID"));
                System.out.println(result+" result value");
                found = true;

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    //result="ssa";
    return result;
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
```

Comment: `' AND ? 23:59:59.999'` is a literal string in the query (so the `?` isn't a bind parameter).

Comment: It should be `WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? and time = ?`. If the "Parameter index out of range" error hadn't happened, it'd just have failed with "Syntax error" instead, since what you have is very bad SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have fixed it just after posting the question

```
public String getSpecificSpot(String day, String hour) {

    String result = "";
    int dayNo= Integer.parseInt(day);


    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    //System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    String monday = "";
    monday = df.format(cal.getTime());
    //System.out.println(monday);

    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, dayNo);
    String currentDay = df.format(cal.getTime());
    String currentDay2= currentDay;
    System.out.println("Current DAY: "+currentDay);

    boolean found = false;
    Connection c = DBHelperClass.getConnection();
    String query = "Select * from timetableslot WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? and time= ? ";
    if (c != null) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement inserter = c.prepareStatement(query);
            inserter.setString(1, currentDay + " 00:00:00.00");
            inserter.setString(2, currentDay2+ " 23:59:59.999");
            inserter.setString(3, hour);

            System.out.println("validating user: " + query);
            ResultSet resultSet = inserter.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {

                //result = resultSet.getInt("classID");
                result= String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("slotID"));
                System.out.println(result+" result value");
                found = true;

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    //result="ssa";
    return result;
}
```